Persistent npm Installation Issues Despite Multiple Troubleshooting Attempt
I've been encountering a persistent issue with installing npm, the Node.js package manager, which is preventing me from running npm commands successfully. Despite following numerous troubleshooting steps, including reinstalling Node.js multiple times, setting the correct PATH environment variables, and updating npm, the problem remains unresolved.
The steps I've taken so far include:
Reinstalling Node.js: I have uninstalled and reinstalled Node.js several times to ensure a clean installation, but the issue persists.
Updating npm: I've tried updating npm to the latest version, both through npm itself and by downloading the latest Node.js package that includes npm, but without success.
Setting Environment Variables: I've checked and set the PATH environment variable to ensure that it correctly points to the Node.js installation directory, but this hasn't resolved the issue.
Clearing npm Cache: I've attempted to clear the npm cache using the npm cache clean --force command, but it did not fix the problem.
Running as Administrator: On Windows, I've run the command prompt as an administrator to avoid any permission-related issues, but the issue still occurs.
Despite these efforts, I continue to face problems with npm installation, and it's unclear whether the issue is related to a deeper system conflict, a corrupted installation, or another underlying factor. Further investigation and potentially more advanced troubleshooting steps are needed to diagnose and resolve the problem.

Without looking step by step at what you're specifically doing it's difficult to come up with useful ideas.
First of all try the steps provided here to see if you actually have uninstalled old versions of Node completely. Then you might want to look into nvm-windows, which manages different Node versions in parallel and installs them automatically for you.
If even this doesn't work, there might be something wrong with your OS or you might be missing some crucial piece of software that allows Node or npm to install successfully.
